# Adding in Style Ref to Drop down in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm rewriting a code I found online.  I want to have a drop down YES/NO in parent field.  If YES is selected, I want a second field to prefill with a field I have already create and has been prefilled with Style Ref. I'm trying to do this so the person filling out the form doesn't have to enter the same information several times.  I keep getting an error for the item in bold. Experienced VBA workers- what would you do to fix this?

```
Sub PopulateddStatus()
    Dim xDirection As FormField
    Dim xState As FormField
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xDirection = ActiveDocument.FormFields("PARENT FIELD")
    Set xState = ActiveDocument.FormFields("DEPENDENT FIELD")
    If ((xDirection Is Nothing) Or (xState Is Nothing)) Then Exit Sub
    With xState.DropDown.ListEntries
        .Clear
        Select Case xDirection.Result
            Case "Yes"
               ** .Add (StyleRef (Style4)\ *MERGEFORMAT)**
            Case "No"
                .Add "Carrier Here"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm currently receiving a Compile/Syntax error.

Comment: I'd read the manual.

Comment: During the debugging stage I'd also remove the on error statement.

Comment: My apologies for the ignorance here- as I can see you are an experienced user.  Which manual are you referring to?

Comment: In the VBIde put the cursor on ListEntries and press F1

Comment: Apologies for freeflow's snarkiness, I guess they've forgotten what it's like to be learning VBA.

It looks like you're trying to add a styleref field to a formfield dropdown, which is not possible. If that's not the case, please clarify.

A more general issue with your code is that you're using legacy formfields, which require the document to be protected for forms for them to work. Then the form must be unprotected for you to edit those formfields.

Comment: OMG this was so helpful. I've been looking at the manual since they replied this morning and I could not make sense of it.  Thank you for your assistance here!

Comment: Can you, instead, use a Mapped Content Control which will instantly replicate information throughout a document. https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtFhIqK0gec

Comment: Here are some references, but this is not an easy learning curve. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-language-reference http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=1565927257/balancecheckbookA/